# For loop not executing as many times specified

Tags: c

I have tried this on different ides but still, the problem persists, sometimes the loop executes as desired and sometimes not.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void main()
{
    int n;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    char s[50];

    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        gets(s);
        puts(s);
    }
}
```

the loop should have run for n times but it goes on for n-1 times.

Comment: Hint: What is in the input stream immediately *after* your numeric value input? Bigger Hint: what key did you press immediately *after* pressing the numeric keys that make up your number? Final Hint: What does `gets` (a function you should *never* use) read and under what condition does it *stop* reading?

Comment: The loop is executing `n` times, clearly.  You just think it isn't, based on an incorrect understanding of what strings you're reading with `gets` (which is deprecated and should never be used by the way).  You can trivially prove it to yourself:  At the top of the loop, add `printf("Iteration %d\n", i);` and you will see the full iteration count, with `i` running from `0` to `n-1`.

Comment: @TomKarzes thanks for your response! I am only a noob out here :)

Comment: You should describe exactly for what inputs (the digit and the strings) the behaviour is different from the one expected so that people can reproduce your problem. With use inputs otherwise it becomes a guessing game leading to nowhere.

Answer (score 0):

`gets()` reads a line until *newline character* found. Since there is a newline in the input from `scanf("%d",&n)` when the `gets()` function call next to it, it will read this new line and return without reading further. To handle this problem you can use a `getchar();` after `scanf("%d",&n);` See the change in bellow:

```
#include<string.h>
#include<stdio.h>

void main()
{
    int n;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    getchar();
    char s[50];

    for(int i=0;i<n;i+=1)
        {
            gets(s);
            puts(s);
        }
}
```

Comment: Please also tell the OP about not using `gets()`